# object created within a class gets access to private fields.. and objects created in a different class don't why?

Tags: java

First of all i created a class called `PrivateShirt1` and called a private field name after creating an object of the class within the same class file, and it worked.

```
public class PrivateShirt1{
   private String name;

   public static void main(String args[]){               
       PrivateShirt1 s1=new PrivateShirt1();
       s1.name="hi";

       System.out.println(s1.name);    
   }
}
```

next i created a separate file called `PrivateShirt2` in which i put the main method of `PrivateShirt1` and performed the function of  compiling and calling it. After the modifications the files `PrivateShirt1` and `PrivateShirt2` look like this:

```
public class PrivateShirt2{ 

  public static void main(String args[]){               
     PrivateShirt1 s1=new PrivateShirt1();
     s1.name="hi";

     System.out.println(s1.name);    
  }


public class PrivateShirt1 {
   private String name;    
}
```

and when i compiled the `PrivateShirt2` file, it gave an error that the attribute i was trying to call is private.

but then why did this not happen in the previous example? I mean, objects were created in both the cases and hence the rules should be equal for both, right? so why then this partial treatment? could anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at java access control.  The name variable in PrivateShirt1 has private access.  Meaning that field can only be referenced from inside that class.  PrivateShirt2 does not have access to that field.  The reason your first call worked is because it was called within PrivateShirt1

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Encapsulation: A language mechanism for restricting access to some of the object's components. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: Whoops sorry I have been writing js all day.  Good catch

Answer (score 0):

`private` modifier means that you can access it only from the code in the Class. Therefore you can access a `private` member from a `static` method or even an inner class.